# Angular – Socket.io emit not working

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io

I'm totally new to working with sockets so please don't bear.

I have an application, where the users can chat with others within a group and I use socket.io to check wherever a user has sent a new message to update it on all client sites.

I followed this guide for a socket.io application: https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

After I set up my project with this guide, the connection seems fine. I get a `Disconnect` and `Connection` log and no errors appear, but when the user sends a message I get no messages from the server or client. I logged the socket object and it says there is no connection. Here the code snippet from the client and server script.

Client: https://pastebin.com/z9GF1UyN
Server: https://pastebin.com/Pevc8xXY

I really think, I just missed something

Console.log(socket):

```
Socket {io: Manager, nsp: "/v1", json: Socket, ids: 0, acks: {…}, …}
connected : false
disconnected : true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I didn't know that the URL does not include a directory. I changed my API Url from localhost/v1 to localhost and all is working fine now!